# Find value of a string given a superstring regex

Tags: regex

How can I match for a string that is a substring of a given input string, preferable with regex?

Given a value: `A789Lfu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH`, construct a regex that would match a string where the string is a substring of the given value.

Expected matches:

- `MatchMe`
- `ENOTST`
- `891`

Expected Non Match

- `foo`
- `A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH_extra`
- `extra_A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH`
- `extra_A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH_extra`

It seems easier for me to do the *reverse*: `/\w*MatchMe\w*/`, but I can't wrap my head around this problem.

Something like how SQL would do it:
`SELECT * FROM my_table mt WHERE 'A789Lfu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH' LIKE '%' || mt.foo || '%';`

Comment: why not do the reverse if it's easier?

Comment: I guess a disjunction of all possible sub-strings is not an option? `^A|7|8|...|A7|78|...$`

Comment: what language do you write the code in?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Typescript

Comment: @Mohammad because that string is unknown at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Prefix suffixes

You could alternate prefix suffixes, like turn the superstring `abcd` into a pattern like `^(a|(a)?b|((a)?b)?c|(((a)?b)?c)?d)$`. For your example, the pattern has 1253 characters (exactly 2000 fewer than @tobias_k's).

Python code to produce the regex, can then be tested with tobias_k's code ([try it online](https://tio.run/##lZBBS8QwEIXv@RVDEJJgKagHu6CIB8GDux7cm6xL7KZupMmEdArKur@9JtuCCCqYU5j53pt5E95pi/6sCnEYrAsYCaJhTUQHlkwkxLaDqaHrund9q8kwRnAJ/Pq8mt01fTU7mWuqt3NzerO4Xz4sbzkLqS@epIBjEB@ifEXr5ZdeUgFC7vbqarcXZYPRaVIqs@pIMPaCuEn6Rz7Z8gL46Jx/aRxfsWc9Ig1iLh5Wufhpl7V5o6gTw2B8/FBY/674Dzu5r5juOpNv1LYymtJlSoYCOgW2A48EC/QGUlRI9/SQI6q/Rd8FKa9iIVpPUiQeQtZuhBqGTw)):

```
from itertools import accumulate

t = "A789Lfu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH"
p = '^(' + '|'.join(accumulate(t, '({})?{}'.format)) + ')$'
```

#### Suffix prefixes

Suffix prefixes look nicer and match faster: `^(a(b(c(d)?)?)?|b(c(d)?)?|c(d)?|d)$`. Sadly the generating code is less elegant.

#### Divide and conquer

For a shorter regex, we can use divide and conquer. For example for the superstring `abcdefg`, every substring falls into one of three cases:

- Contains the middle character (the `d`). Pattern for that: `((a?b)?c)?d(e(fg?)?)?`
- Is left of that middle character. So recursively build a regex for the superstring `abc`: `a|a?bc?|c`.
- Is right of that middle character. So recursively build a regex for the superstring `efg`: `e|e?fg?|g`.

And then make an alternation of those three cases:

```
a|a?bc?|c|((a?b)?c)?d(e(fg?)?)?|e|e?fg?|g
```

Regex length will be Θ(n log n) instead of our previous Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

The result for your superstring example of 25 characters is this regex with 301 characters:

```
^(A|A?78?|8|((A?7)?8)?9(Lf?)?|Lf?|f|(((((A?7)?8)?9)?L)?f)?u(8(9(1(Ma?)?)?)?)?|89?|9|(8?9)?1(Ma?)?|Ma?|a|(((((((((((A?7)?8)?9)?L)?f)?u)?8)?9)?1)?M)?a)?t(c(h(M(e(2(E(N(O(T(S(TH?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?|c|c?hM?|M|((c?h)?M)?e(2E?)?|2E?|E|(((((c?h)?M)?e)?2)?E)?N(O(T(S(TH?)?)?)?)?|OT?|T|(O?T)?S(TH?)?|TH?|H)$
```

#### Benchmark

Speed benchmarks don't really make that much sense, as in reality we'd just do a regular substring check (in Python `s in t`), but let's do one anyway.

Results for matching all substrings of your superstring, using Python 3.9.6 on my PC:

```
 1.09 ms  just_all_substrings
25.18 ms  prefix_suffixes
 3.47 ms  suffix_prefixes
 3.46 ms  divide_and_conquer
```

And on TIO and their "Python 3.8 (pre-release)" with quite different results:

```
 0.30 ms  just_all_substrings
46.90 ms  prefix_suffixes
 2.24 ms  suffix_prefixes
 2.95 ms  divide_and_conquer
```

Regex lengths (also printed by the below benchmark code):

```
 3253 characters - just_all_substrings
 1253 characters - prefix_suffixes
 1253 characters - suffix_prefixes
  301 characters - divide_and_conquer
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVXJbtswEL3rKwg3gahacSwHRRMBrtBDgB6aFmhzExyBlimbiSipFBUkUPzt7pBa6C2LLqaHM/PePHKGxbNc5dnFZSE2m0TkHEnGKZOI8SIXEglaUCKt/p@lfZikQuZ5WnZuJI4rXqVEUsta0ATdV6WMSJpGZTUvpWDZssTS8S0En6CyEhka3OEBGiL7xR7d5yzDMmT@wwwluUAMsQwJki0pHrsopbDpODr27U/FPphYNvS66KHnOAA2cE4GDcFC0IQ9Ab0EfugBOfsO29vkTH1YusjG9doJ6rU9AkROpM5tOyd2k7tJGjUQ7@dOWSl3AELfP/NmAFN7a1yPAcoANXs9nkqrMRfskS1oRLJFFOfZv4oKDasdDKctMur7hK6fCC9S6iMyj9H0G8KYBHMniJ2gdxJ0SZ/QFCV2LcPxbB3Y1rbesdJbhp4/83dOyIThWq/Xdawq2cqr1dB7hueBaHs8abLUPClOloETvMYTNHqF6NlEK/g62Xjd8n2fbFkVVJt22GaQqLl1vYklyjpF3j6szioP/CZH/VRl6@AFyoPqDDfOFoCYofNzNOmNcAkkYYqKOfnQB1d9d2SoVrAwcivLEE7RkE5pInV8X2SbwKjClqt9l4M03a3vrnuo8rodQbdJAv5HWmRb377DYgEDKRcl4B6ZMu5@Z7v77ege6RXXsixVyOD718urn0l1eeXdEBmvbujk@tfv27@3P2BsGBDwDGVYSiKkX8q8mFmHc0jvmll0fIg1jnlh/HTYztya6f6WFIZE0d4yrrgBCUFHcc4LllLYGmnrtoqgDOakwEfclCpdNcDK0g3SCKu4dBo3cAW4SawZtBuqFLfzGkVRRjiNIsdqPCFfs7D/6L6CUpZyVfq28xEc@/TLAsUrIkgMr0yJzmx0qtX4KLbCiIyiF61ob0JreFDUYJh2rvicCtjzxr1NvZFg4XCdmwcSp4TPF8Tvzsltw6bNDzwQ563FwHXVjiYJ4iVSZWKd@DPy6MXRGk0c1Nk@veVz2dYOq9EjSMbyzDk0RSxLcmez@Q8)):

```
from timeit import repeat
import re
from itertools import accumulate

def just_all_substrings(t):
    return "^(" + '|'.join(t[i:k] for i in range(0, len(t))
                                  for k in range(i+1, len(t)+1)) + ")$"

def prefix_suffixes(t):
    return '^(' + '|'.join(accumulate(t, '({})?{}'.format)) + ')$'

def suffix_prefixes(t):
    return '^(' + '|'.join(list(accumulate(t[::-1], '{1}({0})?'.format))[::-1]) + ')$'
    
def divide_and_conquer(t):

    def suffixes(t):
        # Example: abc => ((a?b)?c)?
        regex = f'{t[0]}?'
        for c in t[1:]:
            regex = f'({regex}{c})?'
        return regex

    def prefixes(t):
        # Example: efg => (e(fg?)?)?
        regex = f'{t[-1]}?'
        for c in t[-2::-1]:
            regex = f'({c}{regex})?'
        return regex

    def superegex(t):
        n = len(t)
        if n == 1:
            return t
        if n == 2:
            return f'{t}?|{t[1]}'
        mid = n // 2
        contain = suffixes(t[:mid]) + t[mid] + prefixes(t[mid+1:])
        left = superegex(t[:mid])
        right = superegex(t[mid+1:])
        return '|'.join([left, contain, right])

    return '^(' + superegex(t) + ')$'

creators = just_all_substrings, prefix_suffixes, suffix_prefixes, divide_and_conquer,


t = "A789Lfu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH"

substrings = [t[start:stop]
              for start in range(len(t))
              for stop in range(start+1, len(t)+1)]
def test(p):
    match = re.compile(p).match
    return all(map(re.compile(p).match, substrings))

for creator in creators:
    print(test(creator(t)), creator.__name__)
print()

print('Regex lengths:')
for creator in creators:
    print('%5d characters -' % len(creator(t)), creator.__name__)
print()

for _ in range(3):
    for creator in creators:
        p = creator(t)
        number = 10
        time = min(repeat(lambda: test(p), number=number)) / number
        print('%5.2f ms ' % (time * 1e3), creator.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Interesting. Might be a bit easier to read with optional suffixes, i.e. `a(b(c(d)?)?)?|b(...` This also seems to improve evaluation speed. Despite being longer, my regex takes just ~10 us per execution for the asserts, whereas yours takes ~200 us; but using suffixes instead of prefixes it takes 10 us, too. The construction is not quite as nice, though: `p3 = '^(' + '|'.join(list(accumulate(t[::-1], lambda a, b: f'{b}({a})?'))[::-1]) + ')$'`

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, that's what I had first, but then I didn't like those reversals and didn't like the extra numbers in `'{1}({0})?'.format` (which you could use instead of your lambda). I suspected it would be faster, but chose the more elegant code. I'd say if we want speed, we wouldn't be doing this at all :-). We'd use `s in t` like you already mentioned.

Comment: That last one is really nice, pity I can't upvote twice. Clever (in a good way), short, and with ~17 us still quite quick.

Comment: @tobias_k Added a benchmark section. Yours seems much faster. Testing only matching substrings, though.

Answer (score 1):

One way to "construct" such a regex would be to build a disjunction of all possible substrings of the original value. Example in Python:

```
import re

t = "A789Lfu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH"
p = "^(" + '|'.join(t[i:k] for i in range(0, len(t))
                           for k in range(i+1, len(t)+1)) + ")$"

good = ["MatchMe", "ENOTST", "891"]
bad = ["foo", "A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH_extra", 
       "extra_A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH", 
       "extra_A789L<fu891MatchMe2ENOTSTH_extra"]
assert all(re.match(p, s) is not None for s in good)
assert all(re.match(p, s) is None for s in bad)
```

For the value `"abcd"`, this would e.g. be `"^(a|ab|abc|abcd|b|bc|bcd|c|cd|d)$"`; for the given example it's a bit longer, with `3253` characters...

Comment: I think thought would work, but it would be O(n^2)

Comment: @TedArmstrong Yes, it is kind of ridiculous. Without regex, you'd just test if `s in t`. Looking forward to seeing a better approach.